# Is there a way to take data from a django form and upload it to database?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pull data from a Django form and upload it to the database.

Here are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category}"
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

class Listing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,  default = None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 128)
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'listing')
    url = models.URLField(max_length = 350, blank = True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='listings')
    watchers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True, related_name='listings')
```

So, when a user adds a new listing, they should choose from categories. Here is how I did it after trying for quite a bit:

```
def new_listing(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bid = Bid(amount = int(request.POST['bid']))
            bid.save()
            listing = Listing()
            listing.bid = bid
            listing.user = request.user
            listing.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            listing.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            listing.url = form.cleaned_data['url']  
            listing.save()
            listing = Listing.objects.reverse()[0]
            for category in form.cleaned_data['category']:
                listing.category.add(category)
```

The issue here is that I have to first save the listing, then pull it again and manually add *Categories*. I am just wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this? Or is this how it is done in Django? Cause' I had a really hard time trying to do it cleaner.

Also, the form is Django generated like this:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'url', 'category']
```

Also, also, is this a good practice for creating forms, or should I go with `forms.Form`?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need to `save` before `add` when dealing with many to many relationships.
You don't need to do your reverse lookup though, and `add` accepts many objects, not just one as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)

```
listing.save()
listing.category.add(*form.cleaned_data["category"])
```

As for the ModelForm, it's fine to use it since you're trying to get a form to create a model. If it was a custom form to do something else, you'd need to use `forms.Form`

Comment: No worries. I highly recommend reading the documentation thoroughly when you have such questions, it's really well made and holds a lot of answers.
Django is a big framework, and sometimes you do things one way, and you realize Django has already a built-in way of dealing with it.
Good luck in your journey!